# Using Back to view my Activity page shows me data that's almost 2 weeks old?

Tags: bug, profile-page, back-button

I was looking through some of my reviews because I wanted to know what happened to some questions I had reviewed earlier, and discovered clicking on a link from the Activity page then using the Back button would display me the page as it was almost 2 weeks ago.

Page while viewing it:

[image]

Page when hitting the Back button:

[image]

I found this extremely confusing until I realized what was happening.

Switching between the filters (all, accepts, posts, etc) also displays old data, but clicking on the Activity tab correctly refreshes the page and gives me current data.

Can the Back button take us to the *most recent* cached data, and not some data from almost 2 weeks ago?

(Not sure if it matters or not, but I'm using Chrome)

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the same for a while. I assumed it was a bug on the Chrome side of things.

Comment: That's chrome caching. Goes way back sometimes. Clear your cache & it'll go away.

Comment: @Mat I don't think it is, because on most other pages the Back button takes me to the *most recent* copy of the page, such as the Reputation page. It's only the Activity page that I've noticed it using a much older copy of the data. It does go away when I clear the cache, but I don't think that step should be necessary :)

Comment: @Rachel: I've seen the exact same thing (was a bit baffled at seeing comments I'd deleted _weeks_ earlier while looking for something in my activity). Went away with a cache clear.