# Everything tagged with [status-norepro] on Meta should be automatically closed as not reproducible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, close-reasons, off-topic

The [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) wiki states:

> This tag indicates that the site developers were unable to recreate the behavior described in a bug report.

The not reproducible close reason states (emphasis mine):

> **The problem described here can no longer be reproduced.** Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

Can we automatically close questions tagged [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)? Or, at the very least, when the community sees norepro questions, can we close them with this reason?

It may be better to simply stick the norepro questions into meta's CV review queue, too.

---

So, I've been VTCing many of the [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) questions, and **every single one I've VTCed so far has been onholdified**. That, honestly, is the strongest argument for this.

Comment: I suppose where I say close, I mean onholdificate, but that's a little unwieldy.

Comment: No, you mean close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a question, [I'm time-travelling aka there seems to be something wrong with the caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134748/im-time-travelling-aka-there-seems-to-be-something-wrong-with-the-caching), that's tagged [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

It has been reproduced by Rachel, Mat and Bart: [Using Back to view my Activity page shows me data that's almost 2 weeks old?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176298/using-back-to-view-my-activity-page-shows-me-data-thats-almost-2-weeks-old?lq=1). Though it might not be anything to do with SE, you have to read the question and check to see whether there's anything there, not assume that you're correct because a tag-wiki tells you that you must be.

I recognise that people have been voting with you, but to ask yourself in reverse, why has no one voted until now?

I actually [dislike the random closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188387/allow-custom-close-reasons-that-are-not-off-topic) of these questions as off-topic. I think it sends a bad message.

So, yes, go forth and close some, if you really feel you must, but I do not see the point and please be careful of what you're doing; don't close everything just because of a tag. There are far more duplicates out there and that it would probably be more helpful to close.

Comment: I can agree with this. I apologize for the somewhat arbitrary voting; I gave each a cursory check first, though it was more of an experiment in close behavior.I'm thinking that maybe this meta off-topic close reason should be removed, since it doesn't serve much purpose... it's a weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think in many cases only the OP can tell if the issue has gone away (fixed) or not. In which case OP may vote to close. Automatic closure may cause dissonance.

The idea of moving norepo tagged posts to CV review queue seems good.

Comment: Then the close reason is useless; if only the OP knows when the question should be closed with that reason, why have it? Additionally, if the community marks a question as not reproducible, shouldn't it be synonymously closed as not reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Now if mods marks [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) OP can provide more detailed reproduction scenario. With auto close this will be limited. 7 days on hold would kinda help, of course, but is it a good way?

<strike>My second concern is search. Closed questions are not searchable, are they? So if after a month or so someone will reproduce the same bug, he will post a duplicate without even knowing it.</strike>

Comment: Users are free to edit closed posts - in fact, it automatically nominates them for reopening. And yes, you can search closed questions - even specifically filter for them. Take a look at the advanced search options.

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn what I meant is - I never got closed question as my search result. If that's only a coincidence, my second paragraph is void.