# What Are the Current "Fault"and "No-Fault" Closes?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Before the recent change in close/on hold reasons, certain close reasons (e.g. "off topic") would carry an automatic downvote (what I call a "fault" close). Others such as "duplicate," would not (the OP isn't penalized for not realizing his question is a a duplicate, meaning "no fault."

With the new close reasons, which are the "fault" closes (automatic downvote), and which aren't?

Comment: The automatic downvotes have been removed, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190947/is-it-time-to-be-rid-of-automatic-down-votes-on-certain-closed-questions/190954#190954).

Comment: Indeed @Antony. [Closing a question will no longer incur an automatic Community downvote.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190947/is-it-time-to-be-rid-of-automatic-down-votes-on-certain-closed-questions/190954#190954)

Comment: @Bart And I am faster by a few seconds. Yay.

Comment: Flagged for being offensively fast @Antony. :p

Comment: @Bart So, would that be a fault or no-fault flag?

Comment: Fault @AndrewBarber. Anything that will cause him to lose rep.